# "there is no signal driver running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime" despite running in Runtime::block_on

Tags: rust, signals, rust-tokio

I'm writing a commandline application using Tokio that controls its lifecycle by listening for keyboard interrupt events (i.e. ctrl + c); however, at the same time it must also monitor the other tasks that are spawned and potentially initiate an early shutdown if any of the tasks panic or otherwise encounter an error. To do this, I have wrapped `tokio::select` in a `while` loop that terminates once the application has at least had a chance to safely shut down.

However, as soon as the select block polls the future returned by `tokio::signal::ctrl_c`, the main thread panics with the following message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'there is no signal driver running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime'
```

...which is confusing, because this is all done inside a `Runtime::block_on` call. I haven't published this application (yet), but the problem can be reproduced with the following code:

```rs
use tokio::runtime::Builder;
use tokio::signal;
use tokio::sync::watch;
use tokio::task::JoinSet;

fn main() {
    let runtime = Builder::new_multi_thread().worker_threads(2).build().unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async {
        let _rt_guard = runtime.enter();
        let (ping_tx, mut ping_rx) = watch::channel(0u32);
        let (pong_tx, mut pong_rx) = watch::channel(0u32);
        let mut tasks = JoinSet::new();
        
        let ping = tasks.spawn(async move {
            let mut val = 0u32;
            ping_tx.send(val).unwrap();
            
            while val < 10u32 {
                pong_rx.changed().await.unwrap();
                val = *pong_rx.borrow();
                ping_tx.send(val + 1).unwrap();
                println!("ping! {}", val + 1);
            }
        });
        
        let pong = tasks.spawn(async move {
            let mut val = 0u32;
            
            while val < 10u32 {
                ping_rx.changed().await.unwrap();
                val = *ping_rx.borrow();
                pong_tx.send(val + 1).unwrap();
                println!("pong! {}", val + 1);
            }
        });
        
        let mut interrupt = Box::pin(signal::ctrl_c());
        let mut interrupt_read = false;
        
        while !interrupt_read && !tasks.is_empty() {
            tokio::select! {
                biased;
                _ = &mut interrupt, if !interrupt_read => {
                    ping.abort();
                    pong.abort();
                    interrupt_read = true;
                },
                _ = tasks.join_next() => {}
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4126cfd324b6d86f39eb96763cfce808)

This example is a bit contrived, but the important parts are:

- I am intentionally using `Runtime::block_on()` instead of `tokio::main` as I want to control the number of runtime threads at runtime.

  - Although, curiously, this example works if rewritten to use `tokio::main`.
- I added `let _rt_guard = runtime.enter()` to ensure that the runtime context was set, but its presence or absence don't appear to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer to this while I was finishing writing up the question, but since I couldn't find the answer by searching on the error message I'll share the answer here.

As I noted, the example I gave works if run from within a function annotated with `tokio::main`. Looking at the [docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.21.2/tokio/attr.main.html), the `main` macro expands to:

```rs
fn main() {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(async {
            println!("Hello world");
        })
}
```

The example I gave did not call `enable_all()` on the builder (or, more specifically, `enable_io()`). Adding this call to the builder chain stops the panic from occurring. The `runtime.enter()` call I made can also be removed, since it wasn't really doing anything.

Updated example (one of the threads still panics due to a Receiver handle being dropped, but the `ctrl_c` await no longer panics, which is the key):

```rs
use tokio::runtime::Builder;
use tokio::signal;
use tokio::sync::watch;
use tokio::task::JoinSet;

fn main() {
    Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .worker_threads(2)
        .enable_io()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(async {
            let (ping_tx, mut ping_rx) = watch::channel(0u32);
            let (pong_tx, mut pong_rx) = watch::channel(0u32);
            let mut tasks = JoinSet::new();
            
            let ping = tasks.spawn(async move {
                let mut val = 0u32;
                ping_tx.send(val).unwrap();
                
                while val < 10u32 {
                    pong_rx.changed().await.unwrap();
                    val = *pong_rx.borrow();
                    ping_tx.send(val + 1).unwrap();
                    println!("ping! {}", val + 1);
                }
            });
            
            let pong = tasks.spawn(async move {
                let mut val = 0u32;
                
                while val < 10u32 {
                    ping_rx.changed().await.unwrap();
                    val = *ping_rx.borrow();
                    pong_tx.send(val + 1).unwrap();
                    println!("pong! {}", val + 1);
                }
            });
            
            let mut interrupt = Box::pin(signal::ctrl_c());
            let mut interrupt_read = false;
            
            while !interrupt_read && !tasks.is_empty() {
                tokio::select! {
                    biased;
                    _ = &mut interrupt, if !interrupt_read => {
                        ping.abort();
                        pong.abort();
                        interrupt_read = true;
                    },
                    _ = tasks.join_next() => {}
                }
            }
        });
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c440db175ef662a478a0e601fbc84a9a)